# ENSDFSTATE.dat file not found error while running exampleB1.exe using Geant4

Tags: geant4

I am new in Geant4. i installed and build GEANT4 using cmake and visual stdio 17 on windlows 10 and now i am trying to practice its given basic exapmles, So, I build first example using cmake by following the toturial given [here](http://geant4-userdoc.web.cern.ch/geant4-userdoc/UsersGuides/InstallationGuide/html/quickstart.html). The example build successfully and created the exampleB1.exe file. I have set up all environment variables to data installed as given in screen shot 
[image: Environment variable]

but facing the problem of still relating to environment vairiable is the screenshots of error

[image: Output console]

I looked this ENSDFSTATE.dat file but could not be able to solve the problem. Any suggestions/ support is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your "G4ENSDFSTATEDATA" environmental variable is pointing to the wrong data set.  Edit this variable to point to G4ENSDFSTATE2.2 location (i.e. D:\GEANT4\share\Geant4-10.5.1\data\G4ENSDFSTATE2.2 instead of D:\GEANT4\share\Geant4-10.5.1\data\G4PARTICLEXS1.1) and should work fine for that one.  Double check your other environmental variables are correct also.  Looks like G4ABLADATA should be G4ABLA3.1 for example.

Here is the list of all variables from the getting started manual (http://geant4-userdoc.web.cern.ch/geant4-userdoc/UsersGuides/InstallationGuide/html/postinstall.html):

[image: Environmental Variables for Datasets]

Good luck!